# How do I efficiently write to every 12th bit of an array of three 32-bit integers?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm coding on an Arduino R4 Wifi and experimenting with the onboard 8x12 matrix of LEDs. [Per the official documentation](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-r4-wifi/led-matrix/), it is possible to store frames either as an array of bytes:

```
uint8_t frame[8][12] = {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

or as an array of three 32 bit integers:

```
unsigned long frame[] = {
  0,
  0,
  0
};
```

The latter is obviously more memory efficient, but I am having trouble figuring out how to efficiently manipulate specific bits inside of it. For example, if I wanted to turn the rightmost column on using the byte array I could do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  frame[i][12] = 1;
}
```

I, however, cannot seem to find an efficient way to map the same for loop to the array of longs. This is the desired mapping:

```
i =
0 -> frame[0], position 20
1 -> frame[0], position 8
2 -> frame[1], position 28
3 -> frame[1], position 16
4 -> frame[1], position 4
5 -> frame[2], position 24
6 -> frame[2], position 12
7 -> frame[2], position 0
```

I was able to come up with this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  bitWrite(frame[(i+1)/3)], ((7-i) / 3) * 4) + (((7 - i) % 3) * 12), 1);
}
```

This is obviously ugly to look at and seems to be computationally inefficient. It works, but it's not pretty.

Comment: Write the naive code in a readable way and enable compiler optimizations. Only then can you profile and find parts that need better performance. I also think you might have some off by one errors, as the 32nd bit is indexed at 31, which then carries to all other indices

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, but I think you need a way to modify bits by their position? for example, in the first row of `frame`, you want to assign the 20th bit from the left (which is 20th column) to 1? and 8th bit (8th column) to 1? Can you please be more clear on exactly what you want?

Comment: You know when you write arr[n][12] into 8x12 array, you are always writing one byte after the current row (basically [n+1][0]  and [8][0] is after whole array)?

Comment: Anyway what a terrible mapping, if they used `byte columns[12];` it would be just  columns[col]  |= 1 << row;  (col -> 0..11, row -> 0..7)

Comment: @KIIV you're right, writing to bytes instead of 32-bit numbers is much better since the original notation was a 8x12. However, I'm still too lost in their question lol. The question auther can use some bit manipulation if they're trying to set numbers bits. If the case is other than that, then IDK.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of storing an 12x8 bits array is an array of 12 bytes.

As in:

```
uint8_t frame[12] = {};
```

All you need are the simple functions to access individual bits, example:

```
   // assumes x and y aree within bounds.
   inline void led_on(int x, int y) 
   {
       // assert(0 <= x && x < 12)
       // assert(0 <= y && y < 8)
       frame[x] |= (1 << y);
   }

   inline void led_off(int x, int y) 
   {
       // assert(0 <= x && x < 12)
       // assert(0 <= y && y < 8)
       frame[x] &= ~(1 << y);
   }

   inline bool get_led(int x, int y) 
   {
       // assert(0 <= x && x < 12)
       // assert(0 <= y && y < 8)
       return (frame[x] & (1 << y)) != 0;
   }
```